# How can i link my c++ program statically with libstdc++ on osx using clang?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, static-linking, libstdc++

i'm writting c++ program and i want to distribute it on Mac OS X versions 10.6 and above. The problem is when i compile the program with clang and it's dynamically linked with libstdc++ and it causes problems with older systems.

There is a key `-static-stdc++` in gcc but there's no one in clang. How can i link my program statically with clang?

My main goal is to compile binary on Mac OS X 10.9 and be able to run it on earlier versions. Maybe there's a different way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Under Linux, this command works:

```
clang --std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ loopy.cpp -o loopy -static -lstdc++
```

Where `loopy` is of course the name of my program.

### Update:

It appears that [Apple strongly discourages static linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html) so it suggests another approach is needed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091105/confusion-of-how-to-make-osx-app-backward-compatible-how-to-test-them) on creating backwards compatible OS X software may be of use to you instead.

Comment: this doesn't work on Mac OSX: `ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`

Comment: You'll need static versions of all libraries including `libcrt0.a`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844819/how-to-static-link-on-os-x) for more details on that.

Comment: It should be possible to statically link libc++ without statically linking libc. The reasoning for discouraging static linking does not apply to libc++; only to libSystem.

Comment: @andrewrk but how to link with libc++ statically?

Comment: @andrewrk still wanting to know how to link with libc++ statically

Comment: You can use `zig c++` to statically link libc++